# How to save the value of json response in shared preference?

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I have to hit a json service and if the response came true than I have to save the user value in shared preference for future use. How can i do that?

my url is:
http://a.nextput.com/apps/init/4/a/9fe2d2cbaa8332a4633be17b79208181-2y-10-ELVM4HwkaYaCVu6203Zjfus-G/o?aff_id={aff_id}

Variables will be passed by the sdk user. In the above url my variables are-    id: 4 and public_key: 9fe2d2cbaa8332a4633be17b79208181-2y-10-ELVM4HwkaYaCVu6203Zjfus-G

I have made a class and declared a static method. Inside the static method I have to do parsing and save the variables in shared preference.

```
public class InitializeSDK {
   public static void init(final Context ctx, int id, String public_key){
     new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

        }

     }.execute();
  }

}
```

Please tell me how to parse it to get the response and save it in shared preference?

Comment: you can find a tutorial on json parser here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm & for sharedpreferences here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: @pooya I know about json parsing. But in this case if you check the url only one object is showing which is a response. i'm confused how to parse it. Please explain.

Comment: It is still a JSON object with single value you create a new JSONObject and perform jsonObject.getBoolean("success")

Comment: @Pooya Can you code it for me please? I'm unable to parse the single object. Till today I have parsed multiple objects with same method. I'm facing trouble for single one. Please!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code you can use:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

    //TODO: add code to read http request and store the json data in json variable
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    boolean state = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("state",state);
    editor.commit();
    return null;

}
```

Comment: in the line JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json); it says cannot resolve symbol json.

Comment: look at the TODO part I wrote in comment. you need to read the http data. this part is on you. I just implemented the parsing

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suggest you need to get JSON data as a string and you can parse it.

```
    String json = "";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;


    try {
        url =  new URL("http://a.nextput.com/apps/init/4/a/9fe2d2cbaa8332a4633be17b79208181-2y-10-ELVM4HwkaYaCVu6203Zjfus-G/o?aff_id=");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        int data = reader.read();

        while (data != -1) {

            char currentChar = (char) data;
            data = reader.read();
            json += currentChar;


        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return json;
}
```

I call this method inside the doInBackground.